# What is this obscure error in Google Analytics tracking code on a _trackEvent() call?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I am calling the Google Analytics _trackEvent() function on a web page, and get back an error from the obfuscated Google code.  In Firebug, it comes back "q is undefined".  In Safari developer console: "TypeError: Result of expression 'q' [undefined] is not an object."

As a test, I have reduced the page to only this call, and still get the error back.  Besides the necessary elements and the standard Google tracking code, my page is:

```
<script>
  pageTracker._trackEvent('Survey', 'Checkout - Survey', 'Rating', 3);
</script>
```

Results is that error.

What's going on here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This problem seems to occure when the page is not fully loaded yet: http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Google+Analytics/thread?tid=4596554b1e9a1545&hl=en

The provided solution is to wait for pageTracker.cb

```
function trackEvent(target, action, opt_label, opt_value) {
  if(pageTracker && !pageTracker.cb) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      trackEvent(target, action, opt_label, opt_value);
    }, 200);
    return;
  }
  pageTracker._trackEvent(target, action, opt_label, opt_value);
}
```

Comment: Looks good.  Error is gone.  Waiting to see if the results show up in Analytics.  If you don't hear back from me, everything worked.

Answer (score 3):

Actually the answer no. 1 is not correct. That's because pageTracker.cb never gets set (it's an obfuscated property name) with other versions of GA.

You should call upon initialization:
`pageTracker._initData()`

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a bug in ga.js introduced when they added `_initData()` functionality to `_trackPageview()`.  Unfortunately `_initData()` isn't actually called after the conditional.  Hope they fix it before they deprecate`_initData()` for good.

e.g.
This page suggests the above should work without calling `_initData()`:
http://www.google.com/support/googleanalytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=55527